# Startup script to run a shell script as daemon

Tags: debian, daemon, lsb

I am using Debian Stretch with systemd version 231-9.

I need to run some shell scripts and non-daemon programs in background even when I logout.

I used to make simple init.d scripts with LSB header and then case with start option that simply executes "my_script.sh >> /var/log/my_script.log 2>&1 &" to run my_script.sh in background but now Systemd kills them once I close the terminal no matter what I try: &, nohup, setsid, disown.

Can you help me to give a recipe for a proper init.d script that makes any script or non-daemon program run as daemon?

Thank you.

Comment: Did Debian change that "linger" thing yet?  There was a pretty big brouhaha when Debian changed systemd's `KillUserProcesses` default to kill everything, but I thought they caved in and changed it back.

Comment: @DerfK Nope, from `man logind.conf`: KillUserProcesses= ... Defaults to "yes".

Comment: Do you want these "things" start automatically during bootup (when exactly?) and run irrespective of any user sessions, or do you want to start them manually and keep them running after you log out? Do these "things" require any interaction when they start or at any later time?

Comment: @FerencWágner I want it to start at bootup (when entering certain runlevel), and also be able to stop/start manually using `service` command.

Answer (score 2):

If your things are owned by the root user, then `/etc/rc.local`:

```
screen -dmS ThingOne /path/to/thing-one
screen -dmS ThingTwo /path/to/thing-two
```

Or, alternatively, for any user (including root), in the cron table:

```
@reboot screen -dmS ThingOne /path/to/thing-one
# et cetera
```

Comment: I need a proper init.d script, not a workaround with rc.local or cron.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set a script as daemon :

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          foobar
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: foobar
# Description:       more foo for your bars
### END INIT INFO

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting foobar "

    # example 1 - system service
    # /usr/bin/foobar --config /etc/foo.conf start

    # example 2 - run script as user
    # su --login mkaz --command "/home/mkaz/bin/my-script --cmd-args"

    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping foobar"

    # example 1
    # /usr/bin/foobar --config /etc/foo.conf stop

    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/foobar {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Then move your script to init.d folder & set it as executable

```
sudo mv foobar /etc/init.d/       # move to init.d
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/foobar # make executable
```

If you want to launch your script at startup :

```
update-rc.d foobar defaults
```

If you want to remove your script from startup :

```
update-rc.d -f foobar remove
```

If you want to start your script manually :

```
service foobar start
```

Source : https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian